# Storyboard loses navigation bar when segueing via tap gesture

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

My app has two scenes: a UIViewController with a navigation bar at the top, and a UITableViewController.  If I wire up a button in the first scene to segue to the table view, everything looks great.  However, if I wire up a tap gesture in the first scene to segue to the table view, then the navigation bar doesn't display in the second scene in Xcode.  When the app is run, the navigation bar appears as it should, but in the storyboard editor it is gone.

Is there something special that needs to be done to preserve the navigation bar when segueing from one scene to another using a tap gesture?  To implement the tap gesture, I dragged it onto one of the elements in my storyboard, then control dragged from the "tap gesture recognizer" icon at the bottom of the scene to the scene I wanted it to segue to.  Then selected "push" for the segue type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never noticed this before, but I do see the same thing. This seems like a bug to me, but maybe Apple has a reason for doing this.  You can go to the "Simulated Metrics" for your controller, and set the "Top Bar" to be a navigation bar, which will allow you to set the title and add a bar button item if you want.