# Correct way to Add the right navigation button with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a single storyboard with the set of view controllers.
How can I add the right buttons in the navigation bar not on the first view controller?
What I want is displayed on the following screen:[image: story board example]

In the first view controller NavigationItem is added by default (highlighted name "Nearest...") and can not be deleted in anyway.
But all others view controllers do not have any navigation item by default.
Is this OK if I add Navigation Item by drag it by myself (highlighted by yellow with name "Groups list") and setup buttons with Bar Button Item?

version of Xcode: 7.2.1 (7C1002)

Comment: What's the problem after you drag in one Bar Button Item?

Comment: did you mean without dragging Navigation Item before? Then how can I setup standalone BBI (Bar Button Item) for appears as right button?

Comment: I believe you can drag a BBI in storyboard. But normally that is done in code.

Comment: If I drag BBI without drag NI - button appears as first bottom bar element

Comment: I think you can directly drag it to the right side of the navigation bar?

Comment: nope. If I drag BBI onto the right side inside the Navigation Bar - when I release a mouse button, BBI is jumping in BottomBar

Comment: Same discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587465/how-to-add-buttons-to-navigation-controller-visible-after-segueing